# Maven + Java SDK 11 + Java FX: JavaFXランタイム・コンポーネントが不足しており、このアプリケーションの実行に必要です

Tags: java, maven, javafx

簡易なアプリです。最新技術を使っている、Java 11 + Java FX + Maven + Spring の「Hello, world」アプリです。

```
package com.example;

import com.example.beans.TestSpringBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class EntryPoint extends javafx.application.Application {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
    TestSpringBean testSpringBean = (TestSpringBean) applicationContext.getBean("testSpringBean");
    System.out.println(testSpringBean.getTestString());
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Label label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX11!");
    Scene scene = new Scene(label, 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

IntelIJ IDEAには、mavenのcompileをしてみると、特に問題ありません：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`maven-package`も、正常です。ですが構成されたファイルを実行してみると、「JavaFXランタイム・コンポーネントが不足しており、このアプリケーションの実行に必要です」というエラーが出ます：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>OTCJA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.EntryPoint</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/libs
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>com.example.EntryPoint</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### 環境

- OS: Windows 10
- IntelIJ IDEA バージョン：2018.2
- ベンター：確か、[http://jdk.java.net](http://jdk.java.net/11/)です

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: IntelIJ IDEAを使わずに実行した場合(例えばコマンドプロンプト上で `mvn exec:java`実行)も同様でしょうか。私はIntelliJは所有していないので完全に同様の環境は再現できないのですが、私の環境では記載されているコード自体は正常に実行できています。OS、JDKベンダ、IntelliJバージョンなど環境の詳細について追記すると回答が得られやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: @yukihane ご推薦に感謝致します。追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実行の際に[ここ](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)に記載されているオプション（以下）を指定していないことが原因だと思います。

```
--module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

Run > Edit Configurations > JAR Applications > (作成したJar) を選択し、「VM Options」に上記を入力して実行すれば、おそらく動くと思います（試していませんが...）。`$PATH_TO_FX`は`javafx-sdk-11/lib`へのパスです。

Comment: 回答してくださいまして、誠にありがとうございます。未だ動いておりませんが、`$PATH_TO_FX`が未設定の為だと思います。`$PATH_TO_FX`は、環境変数だという理解で宜しいでしょうか。

Comment: JavaFX SDKのインストールディレクトリーのパスです。Windowsであれば、`C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11\lib`とか。インストールしていないのであれば、[このページ](http://www.torutk.com/projects/swe/wiki/JavaFX%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)とかを参考にインストールする必要があります（もしかしたら、IntelliJとともにインストールされているのかもしれませんが）。

Comment: 正常可能の必要な条件がわからないままですが、`mvn compile exec:java`で動きました。これで問題が解決となりますが、未だわからないことが多くあります。例えば、Mavenを使わずに`Run EntryPoint.java`をしてみると、`--module-path $PATH_TO_JAVA_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls`指定および適切なインストールがあるのに、`java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`になります。とにかく、ご支援、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

javafxのjarはjfxrt.jarだったと思います。きっとここへのパスが通ってないんですね。